# In Textsum example model where is: 'train/eval/test' folder?

Tags: tensorflow

https://modelzoo.co/model/textsum says I should:

> 3. Move the train/eval/test data to your workspace 'data' directory.

But I can't find any `train/eval/test` folder at: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/textsum

Where is it?

I wanted to try and run the test summarization model, so I followed the guide above, I checked out https://github.com/tensorflow/models trying to find that folder when following the guidelines but without any success.